# Getting error when trying to initialize WebDriver for Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, webdriver

My web application is written in PHP. I use Eclipse IDE to write my Java code to automate it. I am trying to initialize Firefox, but it isn't recognized. I added the Firefox executable but I get the error below.

My code:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
public class GCBid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\Users\\su5w1n6\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla  Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\Users\\su5w1n6\\AppData\\Mozilla_Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
        FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        FirefoxDriver _driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,firefoxProfile);
        // WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //driver.get("test.cpmtoolbox.com");
    }
}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Specified firefox   binary location does not exist or is not a real
>   file: C:\Users\su5w1n6\AppData\Mozilla_Firefox\firefox.exe
>       Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6b', time: '2013-08-12 15:43:19'
>       System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_20'
>       Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.(Executable.java:57)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.(FirefoxBinary.java:59)
>         at GCBid.main(GCBid.java:15)

Comment: Does it exist? Are you sure Firefox is installed there? It is a weird place for it to be installed, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid needing to place the firefox binary in your code. Go to your environment variables and add firefox's location to the PATH, if it wasn't found by default in Selenium.

Comment: Belated critique: sure, great, but this doesn't answer the problem. Or does it?

Comment: I made a lot of assumptions with this answer. First assumption is that the automation may one day be shared. If that's the case, every person who wants to run this has to go edit this portion of code he wrote for the path to the Firefox binary. Generally good practice not to hard code crucial paths like that. Second assumption is that he needed to do this because Selenium couldn't find the default location of his Firefox install. Selenium's docs detail how to add the binary location in environment variables so that Selenium can start the browser without needing to specify its path in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
File pathToBinary = new File("Firefox.exe location");
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxDriver _driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary,firefoxProfile);
```

or

Just add *Firefox.exe location* to environmental variables